# How do I change the code to whatever I input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I've been working on this code and I'm trying to make it so that what I write will change the code's result.

```
import phonenumbers
from phonenumbers import geocoder
from phonenumbers import carrier
phone_number1 = phonenumbers.parse("+12123456789")
print(phone_number1)
print(geocoder.description_for_number(phone_number1,'en'))
print(carrier.name_for_number(phone_number1,'en'))
phone_number2 = phonenumbers.parse("+12123456789")
print(geocoder.description_for_number(phone_number2,'en'))
```

The result I get depends on what I write in the `phonenumber.parse()` but I can't figure out how to make it what I input change that `phonenumber.parse()`, example:

What is your phone number?

+12123456789

and that makes the `phonenumber.parse()` become `phonenumber.parse("+12123456789")`

There's probably a very simple answer to this which I'm just not seeing...

This is most likely very poorly explained so any type of help would be useful :)

Comment: i am not good add this but i suggest you to check if module phonenumbers.parse() takes an argument as a string or not . then you can change your code a little bit like ``` UserPhone = input()``` then you will compile with ```number1=phonenumbers.parse(UserPhone)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an f string literal. This will format the string passed into the parser with the value of the `user_In` variable. Here is the code:

```
user_In = input("What is your phone number? \n")
number1 = phonenumbers.parse(f"{user_In}")
```